# Subscription prices in App Store Connect and Storekit file

Tags: ios, react-native, storekit, react-native-iap

I've integrated subscription feature using `react-native-iap` library and getting live subscription products from direct App Store Connect, but in the past I've created storekit file for the same and today I found the pricing are different from App Store Connect,
so my question is `Does Apple reject app if both prices are different?`

I got rejection 2 time with same reasons so I'm super confussed here please let me know if I've to correct both version for submission.